# FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE and memory mapped files

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-mapped-files

Not that it's particularly useful, but I'm curious as to why the following works, is it simply because the page still happens to be in memory even after the file is deleted? In which case, if the page is swapped out the data will be lost?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&CloseHandle)> Handle;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&UnmapViewOfFile)> View;

    View v(nullptr, UnmapViewOfFile);

    {
        Handle h(CreateFile(
            L"test",
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            nullptr,
            CREATE_ALWAYS,
            FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,
            nullptr
        ), CloseHandle);

        // write something so CreateFileMapping succeeds
        DWORD sz;
        WriteFile(h.get(), "hello world", 12, &sz, nullptr);

        Handle m(CreateFileMapping(
            h.get(),
            nullptr,
            PAGE_READWRITE,
            0, 0,
            nullptr
        ), CloseHandle);

        v.reset(MapViewOfFile(
            m.get(),
            FILE_MAP_WRITE,
            0, 0,
            0
        ));

        char c;
        std::cin >> c; // File is still in folder
    }

    char c;
    std::cin >> c; // No file!

    std::cout << static_cast<char*>(v.get()); // Still writes
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` follows the unfortunate Windows tradition of referring to an unlink operation as "delete". In fact, the flag only causes the file to be unlinked from the specified directory when the file is closed.

Like other operating systems, Windows only gives ordinary user code the ability to unlink a file from a particular directory. Deleting is always the operating system's decision, taking place when the file can no longer be referenced in any way.

If you look, you'll see the file has in fact been unlinked from the directory, but it will not actually be deleted (and the space the data takes on disk available for re-use) until its reference count drops to zero. The mapping holds a reference.

Comment: This is entirely correct, though I wonder why you say "unfortunate" and "Windows tradition". It _fortunately_ works the exact same way under Posix, and many programs rely on that (PID files are one example where you rely on this exact behaviour).

Comment: @Damon: It's unfortunate that Windows uses the term "delete" because it causes confusion. If they had called it `FILE_FLAG_UNLINK_ON_CLOSE` there would have been no confusion. Yes, it's fortunate that Windows really does do it sanely, only giving ordinary user code access to an unlink capability and only actually deleting when the reference count drops to zero.

Comment: @Damon Unfortunately it doesn't work the same way on Windows. Seems like behavior is FS specific on Windows and not what people usually expect on NTFS.

Comment: @Ivan: I strongly doubt it is FS specific. That would mean 100% legitimate code could crash and burn if you move it to a different disk, no operating system can afford such a thing to happen. Files that still have open handles (such as the one in the map view) are certainly not _physically_ deleted, this just cannot be.

Comment: @Damon You can try the example program from my answer. The quote there says this behavior is FS specific. It might be wrong and behavior might be consistent, but then it is consistently losing data. I guess keeping a memory mapped file in memory while file is deleted is not a usual case for Windows. The thing is on Windows you cannot easily delete such file - `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` is the only way to perform file removal in this case. So this is a very rare corner case I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Windows is different from Linux and other Unix-alikes in this regard. It maintains a separate reference and handle count for each `FILE_OBJECT`. When the last handle is closed, the filesystem unlinks the file and switches it to a "deleted" state. Meanwhile the `FILE_OBJECT` might live longer in a "deleted" state until reference count drops to zero.

Quote from [here](http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel.narkive.com/soMXzSBU/memory-mapped-file-pages-getting-cleared-when-memory-overcommitted):

> The file gets deleted when you close the file handle. After this, if
>   any pages from the view are trimmed and repurposed and then accessed
>   again, the memory manager will try to read them from the file (which
>   is now in the "deleted" state). What happens next depends on the
>   filesystem. NTFS returns an error code (`STATUS_END_OF_FILE`) which
>   causes the memory manager to satisfy the page fault with zeroed pages.
>   As far as I can tell, this behavior is not documented so a future
>   version of NTFS (or a different filesystem) could return a different
>   error, which would result in an inpage exception instead.

That means that once the file is unlinked, swapped-out data **will be lost** and replaced with zeroes.

You can observe this behavior with the program below. It does the following:

- Creates a file of a size equal to the amount of RAM with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`.
- Maps it into memory.
- Deletes the file by closing the last handle to it.
- Fills file content with `0xCD` pattern. Since the file is as large as RAM, this should force pages out of a memory and into a file.
- Prints first 16 bytes of the mapping.

The output says the data at the beginning of the mapping is all zeroes - data has been lost. It is not clear if this can be considered a bug, but as of today this behavior is at least 12 years old and is not likely to be changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    MEMORYSTATUSEX mem = { 0 };
    mem.dwLength = sizeof mem;
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&mem);
    size.QuadPart = mem.ullTotalPhys;

    const HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(
        L"file-under-test",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,
        NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CreateFileW() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!SetFilePointerEx(hFile, size, NULL, SEEK_SET)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SetFilePointerEx() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!SetEndOfFile(hFile)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SetEndOfFile() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMappingW(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CreateFileMappingW() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    void *const view = MapViewOfFile(
        hMap,
        FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE,
        0, 0,
        (size_t) size.QuadPart);

    if (view == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "MapViewOfFile() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    CloseHandle(hMap);
    CloseHandle(hFile); // this removes the file
    memset(view, 0xCD, (size_t) size.QuadPart);

    // Print first 16 bytes
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        printf("%2d: %#x\n", i, ((const volatile unsigned char *) view)[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```