# How to prevent flushing to disk of a memory map opened on a windows temporary delete-on-close file

Tags: windows, winapi, language-agnostic, memory-mapped-files, temporary-files

**UPDATE 2 / TL;DR**

> Is there some way to prevent dirty pages of a windows `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` temporary file from being flushed as a result of closing memory maps opened on these files?

**Yes.** If you do not need to do anything with the files themselves after their initial creation and you implement some naming conventions, this is possible through the strategy explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061543/2573395).

**Note:** I am still quite interested in finding out the reasons for why there is so much difference in the behavior depending on how maps are created and the order of disposal/unmapping.

---

I have been looking into some strategies for an inter-process shared memory data structure that allows growing and shrinking its committed capacity on windows by using a chain of "memory chunks."

One possible way is to use **pagefile backed named memory maps** as the chunk memory. An advantage of this strategy is the possibility to use `SEC_RESERVE` to reserve a big chunk of memory address space and incrementally allocate it using `VirtualAlloc` with `MEM_COMMIT`. Disadvantages appear to be (a) the requirement to have `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` permissions to allow using a shareable name in the `Global\` namespace and (b) the fact that all committed memory contributes to the system commit charge.

To circumvent these disadvantages, I started investigating the use of **temporary file backed memory maps**. I.e. memory maps over files created using the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` flags combination. This appears to be a recommended strategy that according to e.g. [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/its-only-temporary) should prevent flushing the mapped memory to disk (unless memory pressure causes dirty mapped pages to be paged out).

I am however observing that closing the map/file handle before the owning process exits, causes dirty pages to be flushed to disk. This occurs even if the view/file handle is not the one through which the dirty pages were created and when these views/file handles were opened after the pages were 'dirtied' in a different view.

It appears that changing the order of disposal (i.e. unmapping the view first or closing the file handle first) has some impact on when the disk flush is initiated, but not on the fact that flushing takes place.

So my questions are:

> - Is there some way to use temporary file backed memory maps and prevent them from flushing dirty pages when the map/file is closed, taking into account that multiple threads within a process/multiple processes may have open handles/views to such a file?
> - If not, what is/could be the reason for the observed behavior?
> - Is there an alternative strategy that I may have overlooked?

---

**UPDATE**
Some additional info: When running the "arena1" and "arena2" parts of the sample code below in two separate (independent) processes, with "arena1" being the process that creates the shared memory regions and "arena2" the one that opens them, the following behavior is observed for maps/chunks that have dirty pages:

- If closing the view before the file handle in the "arena1" process, it flushes each of these chunks to disk in what seems a (partially) synchronous process (i.e. it blocks the disposing thread for several seconds), **independent** of whether or not the "arena2" process was started.
- If closing the file handle before the view, disk flushes only occur for those maps/chunks that are closed in the "arena1" process while the "arena2" process still has an open handle to those chunks, and they appear to be 'asynchronous', i.e. not blocking the application thread.

Refer to the (c++) sample code below that allows reproducing the problem on my system (x64, Win7):

```
static uint64_t start_ts;
static uint64_t elapsed() {
    return ::GetTickCount64() - start_ts;
}

class PageArena {
public:
    typedef uint8_t* pointer;

    PageArena(int id, const char* base_name, size_t page_sz, size_t chunk_sz, size_t n_chunks, bool dispose_handle_first) :
        id_(id), base_name_(base_name), pg_sz_(page_sz), dispose_handle_first_(dispose_handle_first) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n_chunks; i++)
            chunks_.push_back(new Chunk(i, base_name_, chunk_sz, dispose_handle_first_));
    }
    ~PageArena() {
        for (auto i = 0; i < chunks_.size(); ++i) {
            if (chunks_[i])
                release_chunk(i);
        }
        std::cout << "[" << ::elapsed() << "] arena " << id_ << " destructed" << std::endl;
    }

    pointer alloc() {
        auto ptr = chunks_.back()->alloc(pg_sz_);
        if (!ptr) {
            chunks_.push_back(new Chunk(chunks_.size(), base_name_, chunks_.back()->capacity(), dispose_handle_first_));
            ptr = chunks_.back()->alloc(pg_sz_);
        }
        return ptr;
    }
    size_t num_chunks() {
        return chunks_.size();
    }
    void release_chunk(size_t ndx) {
        delete chunks_[ndx];
        chunks_[ndx] = nullptr;
        std::cout << "[" << ::elapsed() << "] chunk " << ndx << " released from arena " << id_ << std::endl;
    }

private:
    struct Chunk {
    public:
        Chunk(size_t ndx, const std::string& base_name, size_t size, bool dispose_handle_first) :
            map_ptr_(nullptr), tail_(nullptr),
            handle_(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE), size_(0),
            dispose_handle_first_(dispose_handle_first) {

            name_ = name_for(base_name, ndx);
            if ((handle_ = create_temp_file(name_, size)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                handle_ = open_temp_file(name_, size);
            if (handle_ != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                size_ = size;
                auto map_handle = ::CreateFileMappingA(handle_, nullptr, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, nullptr);
                tail_ = map_ptr_ = (pointer)::MapViewOfFile(map_handle, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, size);
                ::CloseHandle(map_handle); // no longer needed.
            }
        }
        ~Chunk() {
            if (dispose_handle_first_) {
                close_file();
                unmap_view();
            } else {
                unmap_view();
                close_file();
            }
        }
        size_t capacity() const {
            return size_;
        }
        pointer alloc(size_t sz) {
            pointer result = nullptr;
            if (tail_ + sz <= map_ptr_ + size_) {
                result = tail_;
                tail_ += sz;
            }
            return result;
        }

    private:
        static const DWORD kReadWrite = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE;
        static const DWORD kFileSharing = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE;
        static const DWORD kTempFlags = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY;

        static std::string name_for(const std::string& base_file_path, size_t ndx) {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << base_file_path << "." << ndx << ".chunk";
            return ss.str();
        }
        static HANDLE create_temp_file(const std::string& name, size_t& size) {
            auto h = CreateFileA(name.c_str(), kReadWrite, kFileSharing, nullptr, CREATE_NEW, kTempFlags, 0);
            if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                LARGE_INTEGER newpos;
                newpos.QuadPart = size;
                ::SetFilePointerEx(h, newpos, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
                ::SetEndOfFile(h);
            }
            return h;
        }
        static HANDLE open_temp_file(const std::string& name, size_t& size) {
            auto h = CreateFileA(name.c_str(), kReadWrite, kFileSharing, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, kTempFlags, 0);
            if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                LARGE_INTEGER sz;
                ::GetFileSizeEx(h, &sz);
                size = sz.QuadPart;
            }
            return h;
        }
        void close_file() {
            if (handle_ != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                std::cout << "[" << ::elapsed() << "] " << name_ << " file handle closing" << std::endl;
                ::CloseHandle(handle_);
                std::cout << "[" << ::elapsed() << "] " << name_ << " file handle closed" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        void unmap_view() {
            if (map_ptr_) {
                std::cout << "[" << ::elapsed() << "] " << name_ << " view closing" << std::endl;
                ::UnmapViewOfFile(map_ptr_);
                std::cout << "[" << ::elapsed() << "] " << name_ << " view closed" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        HANDLE          handle_;
        std::string     name_;
        pointer         map_ptr_;
        size_t          size_;
        pointer         tail_;
        bool            dispose_handle_first_;
    };

    int id_;
    size_t pg_sz_;
    std::string base_name_;
    std::vector<Chunk*> chunks_;
    bool dispose_handle_first_;
};

static void TempFileMapping(bool dispose_handle_first) {
    const size_t chunk_size = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
    const size_t pg_size = 8192;
    const size_t n_pages = 100 * 1000;
    const char*  base_path = "data/page_pool";
    start_ts = ::GetTickCount64();

    if (dispose_handle_first)
        std::cout << "Mapping with 2 arenas and closing file handles before unmapping views." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Mapping with 2 arenas and unmapping views before closing file handles." << std::endl;
    {
        std::cout << "[" << ::elapsed() << "] " << "allocating " << n_pages << " pages through arena 1." << std::endl;
        PageArena arena1(1, base_path, pg_size, chunk_size, 1, dispose_handle_first);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n_pages; i++) {
            auto ptr = arena1.alloc();
            memset(ptr, (i + 1) % 256, pg_size); // ensure pages are dirty.
        }
        std::cout << "[" << elapsed() << "] " << arena1.num_chunks() << " chunks created." << std::endl;
        {
            PageArena arena2(2, base_path, pg_size, chunk_size, arena1.num_chunks(), dispose_handle_first);
            std::cout << "[" << ::elapsed() << "] arena 2 loaded, going to release chunks 1 and 2 from arena 1" << std::endl;
            arena1.release_chunk(1);
            arena1.release_chunk(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/574f6a477edd25a60e19) that contains the output of running the above code and links to screen captures of [system free memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqpDn.jpg) and disk activity when running [`TempFileMapping(false)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gFGD.jpg) and [`TempFileMapping(true)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCQ9J.png) respectively.

Comment: Did I miss the C# in the question, or is this meant to work for interop between C# and C++ clients?

Comment: @theB, the issue is not language dependent but (windows) platform dependent, I added the c++ and c# language tags as these are the largest communities using the platform. I used a c++ sample that allows reproducing the issue, but could just as well have provided a c# one with some interop.

Comment: Do not add irrelevant tags trying to get attention to your question. Use only the tags that are actually applicable to your question. Tags actually have meaning here. Don't abuse them.

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off doing your own memory management, so you can control explicitly when the memory is written to the file?

Comment: @MarkRansom The idea here was to basically have the same behavior as for a pagefile backed shared memory region. I.e. **never** flush to disk (unless a dirty page has to be paged out under memory pressure). Using a temporary, delete-on-close file map had the promise of supporting that without the pagefile solution's disadvantages (commit charge and `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` permissions). I am not aware of other memory management techniques that allow creating and sharing a memory region between processes that offer control on when the OS pager decides to flush dirty pages to disk.

Comment: Why do you need to create the memory map in the global namespace?  Are the processes running in different sessions?  (If so, how are you sharing the memory between them when using temporary files?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston true, it is not required to use the global namespace if running in the same session/admin/local system account, but it would be nice not to have this restriction (e.g. to share between a service & app). Additionally not weighing in that much on the system commit charge is desirable.

Comment: @Alex: note that services always have `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` (unless the programmer has intentionally removed it).  I'm not sure the commit charge should be an issue; in fact, it is probably preferable to use the operating system's virtual memory rather than creating your own.  (In other words, hiding your memory usage isn't necessarily a good thing.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I know, services, admin & local system account have this privilege. I was thinking about the scenario where e.g. a user-space app wants to create (as opposed to open) a mapped region to be shared with e.g. a service. But it may be that this is not a problem after all when simply using a non-global namespace name and my understanding of what can be shared between processes running in different sessions was not correct. Independent of that, I am still interested in finding ways to prevent the disk flushes for mapped temp files.

Comment: @Alex: I don't think that's possible, or at least I don't believe there is a supported solution.  But the question is sound, and should remain open - someone else may know better.  (If you want to experiment, you could try MEM_RESET, OfferVirtualMemory, or DiscardVirtualMemory.)

Comment: Is the allocated size of your temp file exceeding available memory?

Comment: @SimonMourier no, sufficient memory is available. Also it only flushes those "chunks" to disk for which a handle is still open when the view is closed, i.e. if a total of 4 chunks were created, and all of their pages 'dirtied', and a handle remains open for only 2 of them when `UnmapViewOfFile` is called, it only flushes those 2, not the other 2.

Comment: UnmapViewOfFile remarks are very informative (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366882.aspx). Also, the CRT equivalent to FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY is _O_SHORT_LIVED (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx) which states 'Creates a file as temporary and `if possible` does not flush to disk'. The 'if possible' means you can't count on a specific behavior. Nothing's wrong in what you do, it's just not exactly what you expect IMHO.

Comment: @SimonMourier I (and apparently others as well) had interpreted "if possible" to mean "if the page does not have to be swapped out". Also, what I am observing in this specific scenario is not a "lazy flush", but a bulk flush of all dirty pages in a chunk (i.e. a ~100 Mbps disk flush spike), very similar to the effect one sees when calling `FlushViewOfFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the bounty period expired without any answers that provided more insight or solved the mentioned problem, I decided to dig a little deeper and experiment some more with several combinations and sequences of operations.

As a result, I believe I have found a way to achieve memory maps shared between processes over temporary, delete-on-close files, that are not being flushed to disk when they are closed.

The **basic idea** involves creating the memory map when a temp file is newly created with a map name that can be used in a call to `OpenFileMapping`:

```
// build a unique map name from the file name.
auto map_name = make_map_name(file_name); 

// Open or create the mapped file.
auto mh = ::OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, false, map_name.c_str());
if (mh == 0 || mh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    // existing map could not be opened, create the file.
    auto fh = ::CreateFileA(name.c_str(), kReadWrite, kFileSharing, nullptr, CREATE_NEW, kTempFlags, 0);
    if (fh != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        // set its size.
        LARGE_INTEGER newpos;
        newpos.QuadPart = desired_size;
        ::SetFilePointerEx(fh, newpos, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
        ::SetEndOfFile(fh);
        // create the map
        mh = ::CreateFileMappingA(mh, nullptr, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, map_name.c_str());
        // close the file handle
        // from now on there will be no accesses using file handles.
        ::CloseHandle(fh);
    }
}
```

Thus, the file handle is only used when the file is newly created, and closed immediately after the map is created, while the map handle itself remains open, to allow opening the mapping without requiring access to a file handle. Note that a race condition exists here, that we would need to deal with in any "real code" (as well as adding decent error checking and handling).

So if we got a valid map handle, we can **create the view**:

```
auto map_ptr = MapViewOfFile(mh, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
if (map_ptr) {
    // determine its size.
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    if (::VirtualQuery(map_ptr, &mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)) > 0) 
        map_size = mbi.RegionSize;
}
```

When, some time later **closing** a mapped file: close the map handle before unmapping the view:

```
if (mh == 0 || mh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    ::CloseHandle(mh);
    mh = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
if (map_ptr) {
    ::UnmapViewOfFile(map_ptr);
    map_ptr = 0;
    map_size = 0;
}
```

And, according to the test I have performed so far, this does not cause flushing dirty pages to disk on close, **problem solved**. Well partially anyway, there may still be a cross-session map name sharing issue.

Comment: Interesting, though I wouldn't depend on it necessarily working as expected on all versions of Windows.  (Personally I would recommend using a pagefile mapping instead, but there may be edge cases.)  The cross-session issue should be resolvable by ensuring that the service is always given the responsibility of creating the mapping, you just need to take that into account when adding the synchronization. (Note that you can [configure a service so that it can be started without admin privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8380009/886887).)

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes this result was a bit unexpected and I am fully aware that without understanding **why** it is behaving the way it is, this may be a 'volatile' strategy to follow. I am quite puzzled by the very different flushing behaviors observed with changes in the order of opening/closing handles and views. I am hoping someone with more intimate knowledge about the implementation(s) will shed some light on this at some point in the future.

Comment: @Alex It doesn't actually work, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099295/file-flag-delete-on-close-and-memory-mapped-files/51649618#51649618). The problem is that dirty pages are still written to the file, but because file is switched to the "closed" state by NTFS driver, data is simply discarded. If memory pressure occurs, random pages in your mapping will be replaced with zero page. You can check example program in my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

If I take it correctly, commenting out `Arena2` part of code shall reproduce the issue without the need for second process. I have tried this:

1. I edited `base_path` as follows for convenience:

   ```
   char base_path[MAX_PATH];
   GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, base_path);
   strcat_s(base_path, MAX_PATH, "page_pool");
   ```
2. I edited `n_pages = 1536 * 128` to bring the used memory to 1.5GB, compared to your ~800mb.
3. I have tested `TempFileMapping(false)` and `TempFileMapping(true)`, one at a time, for the same results.
4. I have tested with `Arena2` commented out and intact, for the same results.
5. I have tested on Win8.1 x64 and Win7 x64, for ±10% same results.
6. In my tests, code runs in 2400ms ±10%, only 500ms ±10% spent on deallocating. That's clearly not enough for a flush of 1.5GB on a low-spinning silent HDDs I have there.

So, the question is, what are you observing? I'd suggest that you:

1. Provide your times for comparison
2. Use a different computer for tests, paying attention to excluding software issues such as "same antivirus"
3. Verify that you're not experiencing a RAM shortage.
4. Use [xperf](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/xperf/) to see what's happening during the freeze.

**Update**
I have tested on yet another Win7 x64, and times are 890ms full, 430ms spent on dealloc. I have looked into your results, and what is **VERY** suspicious is that almost exactly 4000ms is spent in freeze each time on your machine. That can't be a mere coincidence, I believe. Also, it's rather obvious now the the problem is somehow bound to a specific machine you're using. So my suggestions are:

1. As stated above, test on another computer yourself
2. As stated above, Use XPerf, it will allow you to see what exactly happens in user mode and kernel mode during the freeze (I really suspect some non-standard driver in the middle)
3. Play with number of pages and see how it affects the freeze length.
4. Try to store files on a different disk drive on the same computer where you have tested initially.

Comment: Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/574f6a477edd25a60e19) that contains the output of running the code included with this question, as well as a section that discusses these results in more detail and links to screen captures of [system free memory](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aqpDn.jpg) and disk activity when running [`TempFileMapping(false)`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6gFGD.jpg) and [`TempFileMapping(true)`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iCQ9J.png) respectively.

Comment: I have updated my answer with further observations and suggested experiments.