# Reference counting issue of MapViewOfFile on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-mapped-files, reference-counting

It seems that `MapViewOfFile` increases the reference count of the file mapping kernel object.

Quoted from the MSDN description of [`MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Mapped views of a file mapping object maintain internal references to
>   the object, and a file mapping object does not close until all
>   references to it are released. Therefore, to fully close a file
>   mapping object, an application must unmap all mapped views of the file
>   mapping object by calling `UnmapViewOfFile` and close the file mapping
>   object handle by calling `CloseHandle`. These functions can be called in
>   any order.

Also, from *Windows via C/C++, 5th Edition*:

> The preceding code shows the "expected" method for manipulating
>   memory-mapped files. However, what it does not show is that the system
>   increments the usage counts of the file object and the file-mapping
>   object when you call `MapViewOfFile`...

Despite these, my actual test suggests the opposite. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 64-bit. The test program is as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
  HANDLE h = CreateFileMappingA(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 128, "test");
  void* p_memory = MapViewOfFile(h, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
  CloseHandle(h);
  h = OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_WRITE, FALSE, "test");
  DWORD dw = GetLastError(); // ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
}
```

The `OpenFileMapping` call failed with the last error `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. When I remove the `CloseHandle` call, everything would be fine. This implies that the `CloseHandle` call eliminates the last reference count of the file mapping kernel object and destroys it. This in turn implies that `MapViewOfFile` does not actually increases the reference count of the object.

I want to make sure what is going on, and what is the exact semantics of `MapViewOfFile` with respect to reference counting of the file mapping kernel object.

Comment: Maybe it's an optimization to not increment the handle usage until the mapping is actually opened for the first time?

Comment: I suspect that the implication in the documentation (that the file mapping object can still be used and/or reopened after the last direct handle to it is closed) was unintentional, and that while you do indeed have to unmap the views in order to release all the related kernel resources, that doesn't mean it is safe to close the handle before you're actually finished using the mapping.  (At any rate, if you just keep the handle open, then the behaviour is unambiguous and you won't need to worry about it.)

Comment: @GSerg I have tried to actually write to the mapped view, and then close the handle. But the problem is still there.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it more convincing by using a file as the backing store instead of the paging file:

```
int main() {
    const char* path = "mmf.bin";
    DeleteFile(path);
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
        FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,
        NULL, CREATE_NEW, 0, NULL);
    HANDLE h = CreateFileMappingA(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 128, "test");
    int* p_memory = (int*)MapViewOfFile(h, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 128);
    CloseHandle(h);
    DWORD attr = GetFileAttributes(path);
    if (attr != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) puts("File still exists");
    else puts("File is gone");
}
```

Output: File is gone

So "the system increments the usage counts of the file object" is most definitely not correct.  And I think you disproved that it increments the usage count on the file-mapping object.  Not sure what to make of this, Richter doesn't get it wrong very often.  Nothing in the errata for the book either.  It *might* have worked this way in an earlier version of Windows, not sure since I never got this wrong on purpose.  We'll have to stick with what the SDK documentation actually says:

> A shared file mapping object will not be destroyed until all processes that use it close their handles to it by using the CloseHandle function.

Comment: I think a kernel object is effectively destroyed if it cannot be opened.

Comment: Very strange.  Does it still behave the same way if you've mapped more than 0 bytes?  If so, with the backing file gone, I wonder what happens if you then write into the mapped address space?

Comment: @Lingxi: depends what you mean.  If it is still using up system resources, even if we can't see them, then not so much.

Comment: If you look closely, you will find that I actually mapped 128 bytes, not 0 bytes. The write operation is also OK after the file mapping kernel object is gone.

Comment: "I think a kernel object is effectively destroyed if it cannot be opened", no not necessarily. Just because new handles to an object can't be created doesn't necessarily mean existing handles are invalid.

Comment: @HarryJohnston File gets removed, file mapping object still exists, but is unable to write/read data to/from the file. If you'll try to use this mapping, you will observe data disappearing under memory pressure. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099295/file-flag-delete-on-close-and-memory-mapped-files/51649618#51649618) answer.